# magento check how old customer is

Tags: customer, register

is there any way to check how old customer in terms of registration like one year old customer like that or we have to write code for the same

```
$d1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(4)->getCreatedAtTimestamp()));
$d2 = new DateTime();
echo $yeardifference = $d2->diff($d1);
```

but i give blank value

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, please make these changes it should return your result

```
$yeardifference = $d1->diff($d2); 
echo $yeardifference->format('%a days');
```

This will return the difference in days. You can use other formats available on your php manual.
Thanks.